# Problems with Queries on Date in RavenDB

Tags: datetime, indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

When trying to compare a date property in my MapReduce result in one in my application I get a strange behaviour.

```
var queryDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
IQueryable<VisitsByMediaSourceAndVersion.MapReduceResult> queryable =
    _documentSession
    .Query<MyIndex.MapReduceResult>(MyIndex.INDEX_NAME)
    .Where(mapReduceResult => mapReduceResult.Date == queryDate);
var count = queryable.Count(),
```

When queryable.Count() is called an exception is thrown. Looking at the url from the exception it seems like "Date: 2012-08-22T00:00:00.0000000" is generated as the query parameter, and then the RavenDB-client interprets "22T00:" as a new field name in the index.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>    Message=Url: "/indexes/VisitsByMediaSourceAndVersion?query=Date%253A2012-08->22T00%253A00%253A00.0000000&start=0&pageSize=0&aggregation=None"

Why is this? Is there a work around? Am I the only one with this problem?

I can't recreated this problem in the EmbeddableDocumentStore version of RavenDB, does that make sense? If I remove the date query it returns result, so the index in itself works.

Using RavenDB Client 1.2.0.0 and Server 960.

Grateful for all help!

Full stack trace:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Url: "/indexes/VisitsByMediaSourceAndVersion?query=Date%253A2012-08-22T00%253A00%253A00.0000000&start=0&pageSize=0&aggregation=None"

System.ArgumentException: The field '22T00' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexes() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 819
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.d_*2e.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 635
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c*_DisplayClass82.b__78(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 838
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 376
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 337
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Query(String index, IndexQuery query) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 781
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.PerformQueryAgainstExistingIndex(IHttpContext context, String index, IndexQuery indexQuery, Guid& indexEtag) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 214
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.ExecuteQuery(IHttpContext context, String index, Guid& indexEtag) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 179
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.GetIndexQueryRessult(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 119
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.OnGet(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 91
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 46
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 550
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 316

Source=Raven.Client.Lightweight
  StackTrace:
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.HandleErrors(WebException e) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 422
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 292
       at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 202
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectQuery(String index, IndexQuery query, String operationUrl, String[] includes) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 745
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass43.<Query>b__42(String u) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 727
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:line 548
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:line 520
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 165
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Query(String index, IndexQuery query, String[] includes) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 727
       at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.ExecuteActualQuery() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 462
       at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.InitSync() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 444
       at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.get_QueryResult() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 430
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.GetQueryResult[TProjection](IDocumentQuery`1 finalQuery) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:line 1456
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.ExecuteQueryTProjection in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:line 1376
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:line 1359
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:line 138
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:line 183
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at TotallyMoney.CreditCards.Admin.Web.Controllers.DailyReportController.Report(ReportPostModel reportPostModel) in C:\Development\Git\MediaIngenuity\TotallyMoney.CreditCards\TotallyMoney.CreditCards.Admin.Web\Controllers\DailyReportController.cs:line 33
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:

Comment: What build are you using for the client? What build are you using for the server?

Comment: I upgraded to 1.2.2068-Unstable (latest NuGet) upon this error, no change.

Comment: Any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: Try using a 1.2 server build.

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurred because you were using a 1.2 (now 2.0) client against a 1.0 server.  This is not supported.

You can use an older client with a newer server, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem after I stupidly upgraded my client just because NuGet said there was an update available. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

If it is producing the correct date and you don't need the rest of the data afterwards, could you use a substring to pull only the date, or possibly use a GetDate() around the method queryable.Count()?